# How to represent object from array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following array, which was retrieved from JSON results:

```
<NSCFArray 0x196e3e0>(  
{  
NameID = 3;  
Name = test1;  
},  
{  
NameID = 6;  
Name = test2;  
}  
)
```

I'd like to go through each object via a tableview and assign its values to labels in a custom tableview cell.  How do I access NameID and Name on each iteration?  Do I need to create a class with those two properties and assign to it from the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the array is something like:

```
NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], @"NameID", @"test1", @"Name", nil],
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:6], @"NameID", @"test2", @"Name", nil],
    nil];
```

You can iterate it like this:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [array objectEnumerator];
id obj;
while ((obj = [enumerator nextObject]))
{
    NSLog(@"NameID:[%@]; Name:[%@]",
        [obj objectForKey:@"NameID"],
        [obj objectForKey:@"Name"]);
}
```

Output:

```
2010-02-04 11:41:53.266 x[8739] NameID:[3]; Name:[test1]
2010-02-04 11:41:53.267 x[8739] NameID:[6]; Name:[test2]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an array of NSDictionary so just iterate through the array and cast to NSDictionary then ask for the key to get the value.